# How to create a new partition from free space?

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-usage, fdisk

I want to install Ceph on my laptop for some dev stuff but the problem is Ceph requires a raw disk or partition.

How I can create a new raw partition from my free space?

At the moment my disk is as below:

```bsh
$sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0722C9AB-A32C-4447-8607-F646E10E1CFF

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1050624    1312767    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1312768  394058702 392745935 187,3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 394059776 1000214527 606154752   289G Linux filesystem


$sudo df -h -T
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1,6G  3,9M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p4 ext4      284G  130G  140G  49% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7,8G  539M  7,3G   7% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat      508M   31M  478M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     1,6G   56K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use **gnome-disks** utility as graphical solution resize your current partition and clear the partition removed.
But sometimes resizing the partition can cause some issues so be careful when resizing, make sure to do a disk fragmentation before you resize it.
Usually the minimal size you needed for an installtion is 20GB try to give that partition no less than that.